# Laravel Project NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to get this app to working

https://github.com/hew86i/zkta

But im getting this error:

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 750
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 659
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/var/www/zkta-master/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Can somebody give me a hand to fix this???

Thanks to all!!

Comment: have you cloned this project from github

Comment: Hi @Shaielndra Gupta  yes, i cloned that project.

Comment: what command you have run to `composer update` or `composer install`

Comment: Hi, again, i run composer install....now i try composer update... that update somethings... but the result is the same. @Shaielndra Gupta –

Comment: No i am just aking you have to composer install only

Answer (score 0):

**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php** means the server has got a request to show a page from a route. but the problem is **route not available** in your project. Check your **web** route where the route exists or not.

This is so much common error in laravel. Check your error

Comment: Thanks.I have this. Where i have to check the web route?? thanks and sorry i dont now almost nothing about this... i just want get working this app. '// Authentication routes...
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

});

Route::get('/models', function () {
    return "models";
});
'

Comment: Its ok dear;... You are good to go with laravel. Thanks for your interest in the programming world. If you feel any problem, feel free to contact me as much as possible. @at github https://github.com/arif98741